# How to capture by reference in rust macro

Tags: macros, rust

I have a macro to generate `match` arms:

```
macro_rules! sort_by {
    ( $query:ident, $sort_by:expr, { $( $name:pat => $column:path,)+ } ) => {
        match $sort_by.column {
            $(
                $name => if $sort_by.descending {
                    $query = $query.order_by($column.desc());
                } else {
                    $query = $query.order_by($column.asc());
                },
            )+
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to call it like this:

```
sort_by!(query, sort_by.unwrap_or(Sort::desc("id")), {
    "id" => table::id,
    "customerName" => table::customer_name,
});
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
sort_by!(query, &sort_by.unwrap_or(Sort::desc("id")), {
                ^^^^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
```

So I have to call it like this:

```
let sort = sort_by.unwrap_or(Sort::desc("id"));
sort_by!(query, &sort, {
    "id" => table::id,
    "customerName" => table::customer_name,
});
```

What should I change to be able to use the expression directly in the macro invocation?

Comment: Do you have an [mcve]?

Comment: The error message looks like you are using the macro inside a `loop`, which seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: The first error is: `failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module 'Sort'`. I think there is code missing from your post.  https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d80995a74fa3401c1cbab09006ac534&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a macro is equivalent to substituting the code it expands to into its call site.  This means if the macro expansion contains `$sort_by` multiple times, the code will evaluate the expression you pass in as `$sort_by` multiple times.  If the expression consumes some variable, this will be invalid.

This is in contrast to how function calls work.  If you pass an expression to a function, it will be evaluated before calling the function, and only the result is passed to the function.

If this is the source of your problem, you can fix it by assigning `$sort_by` to a local variable inside your macro expansion, and only access the local variable subsequently:

```
macro_rules! sort_by {
    ($query:ident, $sort_by:expr, { $($name:pat => $column:path,)+ }) => {
        let sort_by = $sort_by;
        match sort_by.column {
            $(
                $name => if sort_by.descending {
                    $query = $query.order_by($column.desc());
                } else {
                    $query = $query.order_by($column.asc());
                },
            )+
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I could not test this, since your example is incomplete.)

Comment: Shoulb be `let sort_by = &$sort_by;` in my case. Thanks!